# Let (X, τ) be a topological space. Show that every sequence in X has a convergent subsequence.

Tags: general-topology, compactness

In the previous parts, 
I was given that (X,τ) is compact. 
I have proved that every closed set of X is compact, and that every infinite subset of X has a limit point.

I was struggling with these question and found this thread

[choose the correct following option?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2396764/choose-the-correct-following-option)

This says that every sequence in a compact space need not have a convergent subsequence? I am very confused, as I don't think there is an error in the question, and I don't think they wouldn't phrase it like this if they were looking for a counterexample.

Is there something I have misunderstood or am missing?

Any help is great appreciated! Also any hints on how to start the proof would be a huge help!

Comment: recommended [thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/44907/4280)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the statement. In a compact **metric** space every sequence  has convergent subsequence but thus is not always true in compact topological spaces. Every sequence in  a compact topological space has  convergent **subnet** but not necessarily a convergent subsequence.

For additional information please search for 'sequential compactness' in Wikipedia.

Comment: So I can't prove that every sequence in the given space has a convergent subsequence?

Comment: No,you cannot. There is a distinction between compactness and sequential compactness of topological spaces. I suggest you take a look at sequential compactness in Wikipedia.  @srh

Comment: That's really helpful thank you!

Comment: @srh In the compact space $\{0,1\}^{\Bbb R}$, there are sequences without a convergent subsequence. Also in $\beta \Bbb N$, if you studied that space.